# Depoy SSAS Project from VSTS to local development server using DevOps method

Tags: tfs, cloud, ssas

We are using TFS agile process in our MSBI project. I am new to VSTS. We created new team project into VSTS and we checked in our SSAS project into VSTS. Now we have to deploy SSAS project from VSTS to local development server. First I tried to build the project from VSTS. It's not worked. I googled but I couldn't find any solution.

Can anyone please tell me how to build and deploy SSAS project from VSTS to local development server step by step?

Comment: You need to provide more details what error are you receiving?

Comment: Is it SSAS Multidimensional or Tabular? What version of Visual Studio on your laptop and what version of SSAS? What about what version of VSTS?

Answer (score 2):

The SSAS projects can be build with the Visual Studio Build step.

The deployment of .asdatabase files (which are the output of the build) can be done with [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174817.aspx)

Comment: Isn't ISDeploymentWizard.exe for SSIS? It won't work for SSAS right?